# What type of colors can KineticJS take?

Tags: kineticjs

There seems to be a lack of documentation on what `Color` is in KineticJS (let me know if I'm wrong)

I've so far discovered through trial and error that I can actually pass in the following to a function like `setFill` from the `Shape` class:

```
someShape.setFill("red");
someShape.setFill("#FF0000");
someShape.setFill("rgb(255,0,0)");
```

You can not however pass in:

```
someShape.setFill(0xff0000);
someShape.setFill("rgb(100%,0%,0%)");
someShape.setFill("hsl(360,100,100)");
someShape.setFill("hsv(360,100,100)");
```

Again this is trial and error. Is there a definitive list out there somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KineticJS passes the fill property to the fillStyle property of the canvas context, which parses the string into a CSS color according to the CSS Color Model:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-color/

I tried each of the fill types that you mentioned, and they actually all worked for me, except for hsv, in Google Chrome.  If they aren't all working, that's because the browser that you're using hasn't fully implemented the color parsing according to the W3C spec